# Display image from SQL database to itext7

Tags: asp.net-core, itext7

I have tried to display image from SQL database to itext7 pdf using ASP.Net Core Entity Framework Core but display only `iText.Layout.Element.Image`. Here are my samples.

```
var query = (from p in _context.Student
                     where p.StudentId == "10001"
                     select new
                     {
                         id = p.StudentId,
                         photo = p.Imgphoto,
                     }).ToList();
        var row = query.ElementAt(0);

Image imge = new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(row.photo));

Table table = new Table(2).UseAllAvailableWidth();

Cell cell = new Cell(1, 2).Add(new Paragraph("Student Details"));
table.AddCell(cell);

cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("id"));
            cell.SetWidth(100);
            table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(Convert.ToString(imge.SetAutoScale(true)).ToString()));
            cell.SetWidth(200);
            table.AddCell(cell);
doc.Add(table);
```

Comment: Why do you *convert the image to string*? That doesn't make any sense, does it?

Comment: I change to this `cell = new Cell().Add(imge.SetAutoScale(true))` and work